# Get values from SQL table for each item in table variable and return null if item doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I've got 3 tables, a results table, an orders table and a table variable with result codes in.

The table formats are something like as followed:

Results

```
| Patient_Order_ID | Result_Code | Result_Value | HospId |
|------------------|-------------|--------------|--------|
| 1                | WCC         | 10           | 123    |
| 1                | RCC         | 8            | 123    |
| 1                | HGB         | 13           | 123    |
| 2                | WCC         | 11           | 123    |
| 2                | RCC         | 9            | 123    |
| 3                | HGB         | 10           | 123    |
| 3                | RCC         | 10           | 123    |
```

Orders

```
| Patient_Order_ID | Date_Collect |
|------------------|--------------|
| 1                | 2014-01-01   |
| 2                | 2014-01-05   |
| 3                | 2014-01-10   |
```

Codes

```
| Result_Code |
|-------------|
| WCC         |
| RCC         |
| HGB         |
```

I want to return the data from the results table for each result code in the result codes table, and return null if a particular code doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
| Result Code | Result_Value | Date_Collect |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|
| WCC         | 10           | 2014-01-01   |
| RCC         | 8            | 2014-01-01   |
| HGB         | 13           | 2014-01-01   |
| WCC         | 10           | 2014-01-05   |
| RCC         | 8            | 2014-01-05   |
| HGB         | NULL         | 2014-01-05   |
| WCC         | NULL         | 2014-01-10   |
| RCC         | 10           | 2014-01-10   |
| HGB         | 13           | 2014-01-10   |
```

If possible, I'd like them to be sorted in the order in which they appear in the codes table.

So far, I've written the following T-SQL:

```
SELECT
    codes.Result_Code
  , results.Result_Value
  , orders.Date_Collect
FROM
    @resultCodes codes
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results results ON codes.Result_Code = results.Result_code
    INNER JOIN Orders orders ON results.Patient_Order_ID = orders.Patient_Order_ID
WHERE
    results.Hospid = @prmHospid
ORDER BY   
    orders.Date_Collect DESC
```

This returns the results almost in the format I want, but doesn't include the null values where needed and doesn't secondary sort on result codes. Any help would be really appreciated.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Move the where criterion to the left join criterion.

Comment: What Laurence said. The where predicate turns the left join into an inner join. If you look at the execution plan you should see it being turned into an inner join. Quoting another answer _Whenever you specify a value from the right side of a left join in a WHERE clause (which is not NULL), you necessarily eliminate all of the NULL values and it essentially becomes an inner join._

Comment: Not 100% sure where you mean - I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OUTER'"

Comment: You shouldn't need a where clause. Move the predicate in your where clause as a second join predicate. As far as the sorting, it isn't sorting because you don't have the "secondary" sort defined in your order by.

Comment: As far as the ordering, you need a keep to explicitly order off of; there is no consistent ordering in SQL without using an ORDER BY.

Comment: @SeanLange I was hoping someone could suggest a way of sorting as I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Order by PrimaryColumn, SecondaryColumn

Comment: @JoshRoberts Did you try the answer i added?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) between Codes and Orders

**SQL Fiddle** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99321/13

```
SELECT
    codes.Result_Code
  , results.Result_Value
  , orders.Date_Collect
FROM
     @resultCodes codes
    FULL OUTER JOIN Orders orders ON 1=1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results results ON codes.Result_Code = results.Result_code AND results.Hospid = 123 AND  orders.Patient_Order_ID=results.Patient_Order_ID  
ORDER BY   
    orders.Date_Collect, codes.Result_Code DESC
```

**Note :** I have wrote the code to match the desired output and thus the ordering is different from your code